# Spark saveAsTextFile in Google Compute taking quadratic time

Tags: pyspark, google-compute-engine

I am working with PySpark on a Jupyter notebook in Google Compute.

I am saving files to cloud storage using saveAsTextFile. The trouble is, it is taking quadratic time in terms of the number of records in the file. This ... doesn't work very well for decently large files.

The command I'm using is

```
bigFile_save.saveAsTextFile("gs://myBucket/myFolder")
```

Is there a way of doing things more efficiently?

As requested, a fuller code sample is

```
# We start with a ColumnSimilarity matrix. This is upper-triangular,
# so we append the transpose
x1 = columnSim.entries.map(lambda x: x)
x2 = columnSim.transpose().entries.map(lambda x: x)
x3 = (x1 + x2)
distMat= x3.map(lambda p: (p.i,p.j,p.value))

# Save the similarity file. Convert column indicies to meaningful
# names

bigFile_save = distMap.map(lambda p: (names[p[0]],names[p[1]],p[2]))

t1 = time.time()
bigFile_save.saveAsTextFile("gs://myBucket/myFolder")
t2 = time.time()

timeDiff = t2 - t1
```

On consideration, what may be happening is lazy execution: names[p[0]] may not be being resolved until the actual printout.

Comment: How is `bigFile_save` RDD created?

Comment: It's from a matrix that got converted to (i,j,value) tuples.

Comment: Can you update question with complete source code? I'm almost sure your performance problem lies somwhere else than saveAsTextFile.